# Ansible command loop with synched array

Tags: arrays, docker, ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to iterate through 2 synched array to run bash commands

list1: a b c

list2: 1 2 3

I want to obtain

`a1 b2 c3`

and not

`a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b2 c1 c2 c3`

I'm tryng with "with_togheter"  but without success

this is my task

```
- name: create volume
  shell: docker volume create {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}
  when: volume_exists|failed
  run_once: true
  with_togheter:
    - "{{ volumename }}"
    - "{{ volumeopts }}"
  tags:
    - dockervolumenested
```

this is the inventory

```
[pgwatch-master]
host.domain

[pgwatch-master:vars]
volumename=["pgw-master-grafana","pgw-master-influxdb","pgw-master-persistent-config","pgw-master-postgresql"]
volumeopts=["--opt o=size=10m --opt device=local --opt type=local","--opt o=size=15000m --opt device=local --opt type=local","--opt o=size=1m --opt device=local --opt type=local","--opt o=size=200m --opt device=local --opt type=local"]
```

this is the error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/rgi/ansible/roles/promotedocker/tasks/main.yml': line 267, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: create volume\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'item' is undefined"}
```

How to do it?

thanks

Comment: There must have bee other error messages as well. `pgwatch-master` isn't valid name of a group.

Comment: There is no filter `failed` in Ansible. It's a test. The task should have failed too.

Comment: The correct loop directive is `with_together` not `with_togheter`.

Comment: Hi @VladimirBotka . The problem was the typo in "with_togheter" !!!! Thanks. I 'll fix all the other problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple demonstration of the [`zip` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters) that will fix your issue. I used 3 input list just to show it can work with more that two (and also because your "abc, 123" example planted a song in my brain for the rest of the day....)

Note: following your comment, you can acheive the exact same result as below in ansible 2.4 by replacing `loop` with `with_list`

The demo playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    list1: [a, b, c]
    list2: [1, 2, 3]
    list3: [do, re, mi]

  tasks:
    - name: Love receipe
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }}, it's easy as {{ item.1 }}, as simple as {{ item.2 }}" 
      loop: "{{ list1 | zip(list2, list3) | list }}"
```

And the result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Love receipe] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 1, 'do']) => {
    "msg": "a, it's easy as 1, as simple as do"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 2, 're']) => {
    "msg": "b, it's easy as 2, as simple as re"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['c', 3, 'mi']) => {
    "msg": "c, it's easy as 3, as simple as mi"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: eheheh thanks. At the moment I have to stay with an ansible server with version 2.4 so I can't use loop, but I'll write a parallel task to be future proof. thanks!

Comment: zip was introduced in ansible 2.3 and you can replace `loop` with `with_item` in this exact case. So it should not be a problem.

Comment: since the zip result is a list of list and `with_items` performs an implicit first level flattening, the correct loop operator to use in ansible 2.4 is `with_list`. See my edit above.